# iterating through multiple array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data array as follows:

```
 totalDays = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"],
 saleDays =  ["tue", "thu"],
 sale = [314,240].
```

I need to modify 'sale' array in a such a way that, sale array should compare with totalDays array with respective saleDays,if sale are present for that day include sale array amount else include 0 in sale array.

for above example i need sale array output as follows:

```
sale  = [0,314,0,240,0,0,0].
```

code:

```
 var arr = _.zip(saleDays, sale);
    var newSale = [];
    var saleAmt = 0;
    _.forEach(arr, function(element) {
        saleAmt = totalDays.indexOf(element[0]) > -1 ? element[1] : 0;
        newSale.push(saleAmt); 
    });
```

but the problem is in this case the indexOf condition is always returns true, So i have tried to use nested loop like:

```
    _.forEach(totalDays, function(dt) {
        _.forEach(arr, function(element) {
        saleAmt = dt === element[0] ? element[1] : 0;
        newSale.push(saleAmt); 
        });
    });
```

But in this case the loop is running 'm * n'times. where m is length of 'totalDays' and 'n' is length of 'arr'. Which i want to avoid and loop should run for totalDays.length times and produced result. Please help me to achieve desire output.

As per @Tao P. R. suggestion, same thing I am trying to use with array of month sale with week startdate.

for eg:

```
totalSale = ['Wed Jun 10 2015','Tue Jun 16 2015','Mon Jun 22 2015','Sun Jun 28 2015','Sat Jul 04 2015','Fri Jul 10 2015']
saleDays: [ 'Mon Jun 15 2015', 'Tue Jul 07 2015' ]
sale: [134,245]
```

Now I have to check in which week of totalSale, sale has been done. For above example I need 
saleData = [134,0,0,0,245,0]
I have tried this by creating array of array for totalSale,

```
var mappedSale = _.map(totalDays, function(d){ 
    for(var j = 0; j < saleDays.length; j ++ ){
        var i = d.indexOf(saleDays[j]);
            if (i<0){ return 0 }
            else return sale[i];
    }
});
```

where,

```
totalDays = [['Wed Jun 10 2015',..'Mon Jun 15 2015'],['Tue Jun 16 2015',..'Sun Jun 21 2015'],...]
```

Will you please tell me what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` to map `totalDays` array with the corresponding value of `sale` like this:

```
 totalDays = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"],
 saleDays =  ["tue", "thu"],
 sale = [314,240];

// Output
var mappedSale = totalDays.map(function(d){
    var i = saleDays.indexOf(d);
    if (i<0){ return 0 }
    else return sale[i];
});

alert(mappedSale); // <-- [0,314,0,240,0,0,0]
```

Equivalent logic with *underscore*:

```
var mappedSale = _.map(totalDays, function(d){
    var i = saleDays.indexOf(d);
    if (i<0){ return 0 }
    else return sale[i];
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're using *lodash* or *underscore*. For *lodash*, the `map` statement may vary.

Comment: P.R I am using underscore. And your answer helps me. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this without any external library:

```js
var totalDays = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"],
  saleDays = ["tue", "thu"],
  sale = [314, 240],
  newSales = [],
  i = -1,
  l = totalDays.length,
  j;
while (l > ++i) {
  j = saleDays.indexOf(totalDays[i]);
  newSales.push((-1 === j) ? 0 : sale[j]);
}
console.log(newSales);
```

With `.map()`:

```js
var totalDays = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"],
  saleDays = ["tue", "thu"],
  sale = [314, 240];
var s;
var newSales = totalDays.map(function(e) {
  s = saleDays.indexOf(e);
  return (-1 === s) ? 0 : sale[s];
});
console.log(newSales);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the other answers, but the logic might be clearer if you did a bit of preparation, creating a `saleData` object as follows:

```
var saleData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < sale.length; i++) { saleData[saleDays[i]] = sale[i]; }
```

This will give you an object

```
{ tue: 314, thu: 240 }
```

If you're using Underscore, you can just say

```
saleData = _.object(saleDays, saleData);
```

In either case, now the `map` is a bit easier:

```
totalDays . map(function(day) { return saleData[day] || 0; })
```